# negative probabilities in the bivariate tree heston model

Tags: options, heston

I am trying to implement the bivariate tree approach for the Heston model by [Beliaeva and Nawalkha](ftp://140.131.110.38/lfchang/public/FE%20TOPICS/reference/10-2-Beliaeva-JD.pdf).

I currently have the problem that given the specifications in their examples, I always obtain negative probability for the stock change to the middle node.

Has anyone else experienced this or can give some pointers as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Please add reference to the paper and specify your question.

Comment: Negative probabilities under Heston have been discussed elsewhere in the Stack. Please check [this](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7047/how-to-avoid-having-negative-volatility-when-applying-heston-model) post as it could be of interest.